# On/Off PushNotification from app using parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I developed app which using Parse PushNotification for iOS,

I have kept notification On/Off option in my app,

What i want to do is when user clicks on notification OFF i want to disable push notification for that device or when user clicks on notification ON i want to enable push notification for that device.

I have wrote this code snippet but it doesn't work,

```
if ([switcher isOn]) 
{ 
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}else{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

Do i need to write some more code ? or am i making any mistake ?

**Plaese help and thanks in advance.**

Answer (score -1):

We should do some change when register Notification in ios8,

```
if (SYSTEM_RUNS_IOS8_OR_LATER) {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    }  else {
        UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
    }
}else{
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
}
```

Comment: But what if i want to unregister notification?

Comment: What is your question? What happens? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: No difference as before

Comment: See this link  http://i.imgur.com/3h3Lscm.png    i want to implement like this, there is an option of notification On/Off in setting from there user can change state of notification